# Opposite of ⌘D in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

⌘D selects the word at the cursor, or the next occurrence of the current selection.

What if I want to select not the next but the LAST (or previous) occurence ? This is especially useful when checking if a variable is present in my function above where I'm currently standing with my cursor.

I've tried a bunch of shortcuts to add before ⌘ like Shift and CTRL and Option, but none do the work.

Comment: what do you mean with `LAST cursor`? The previous occurrence of the selection?

Comment: Yes previous occurence. Realised it wasn't clear I've edited thank you.

Comment: `LAST` is always **after** the current cursor, it is the last occurrence in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `Keyboard Shortcuts` you can open them from `Command Palette` and search for `Selection To Previous Find Match`, by default they are not assigned.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I was looking for! Do you have any suggestion for a shortcut on this one? It's hard to find one who isn't taken that makes sense.

Comment: It depends, i like to use full keyboard so usually i bind all custom shortcuts to numpad, but not everybody likes their keyboard chonky :D After some practice the `double` key bindings where you press and hold `CTRL` while typing other symbols are also nice and easy to use.